# Using Scala array from java

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use some library code written in scala from a java program.
I have a function that returns an Array (a scala Array) and I thought it would be possible to do

```
Tree[] = ScalaObject.myScalaFunction()
```

But the I get this error :

```
[error] found   : scala.runtime.BoxedArray
[error] required: org.grammaticalframework.Trees.Absyn.Tree[]
```

What is the correct way to use a scala array in java ?

Comment: What's the sig of myScalaFunction() look like?

Comment: Do you use scala  2.7? In scala2.8, a scala Array is equals to a java Array.

Comment: Assuming that myScalaFunction() is really returning an array of Trees, have you just tried casting the returned value appropriately?

Comment: The function is actually a call to toArray from a scala.List

    (toArray[B >: A] : Array[B])

I'm using scala 2.7.7
Casting doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With 2.7, you should be able to

```
Tree[] t = (Tree)ScalaObject.myScalaFunction().unbox(Tree.class);
```

in Java.

With 2.8, it will work as you hoped it would.